# showing number of new messages on button when new message comes and when no new message it should not show

Tags: android, notifications, android-imageview

we have a feature to update the app icon with the new pending messages for the user by showing a small number on the right-top corner of the icon and similarly I would like to know if we have method to update a ImageView/ImageButton in android(Here I am  looking to update the icon on the home screen ).

For example, the pic shows the red background icon with the number of messages pending to be read in red and if there are no messages it shows with a gray background.

how can i do this ? if possible please provide smaple code

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569695/android-is-it-possible-to-update-a-imageview-imagebutton-with-a-number-to-show-t

Comment: Did you ask this previously http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569695/android-is-it-possible-to-update-a-imageview-imagebutton-with-a-number-to-show-t ?

Comment: ya but that was for inside application but now i wanted to know about on home screen please guide me

Comment: I added my answer in the thread pointed by MarvinLabs with an example, dont know if it's the standard way to do it but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to implement a 1X1 widget.

[Android App Widget Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

Comment: @user701735 may u please highlight or share how else u achieved this? Might be of help.Thanks