# Drawing number badge like iPhone in Android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

[image: a busy cat]

I want to draw the number badge as shown in the above image on the Chats tab. That number badge shows number of new unread messages in chat. So how can I draw this kind of custom number badge. Is there any inbuilt API in Android SDK? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569695/android-is-it-possible-to-update-a-imageview-imagebutton-with-a-number-to-show-t/5604787#5604787) for widgets/app.

You can use `shapecount.xml`

**res/layout/tabicon.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@null"
    android:id="@+id/rlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mylocation" <!-- Just for test -->
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="50" android:textSize="12dp" android:textStyle="bold"  
        android:background="@drawable/shapecount"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp" android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rlayout"
        android:id="@+id/txtCount" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When creating your tab:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabicon, null);
final TextView txtCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCount);

spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator(view).setContent(intent);
```

Now you can use `txtCount` to update the number in the tab's icon. See the post I pointed out above for an example of TimerTask to test this.

You will have to arrange the layout as you wish also

Comment: hi such a nice way of implementing badge,but i got a problem,when using custom view for tab indicator,the background of the view should be matching others tabs background,how can i access the default tab indicator drawable??

Comment: Finally i hacked into the sdk and got the tab_indicator.xml and other drawables....

Comment: Badge like iphone is really simple to make in android...credit goes to your idea,,,i didn't even knew that we can set a view in indicator of tab :P

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using FrameLayout: [Common Layout Objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all

Answer (score 0):

There is a convenient [library](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger) to achieve this easily. Just a single jar file which can be added to your project.