# Android widget with number

Tags: android

Hi my app has couple of services running in the background. And if there is a "new task", notification pops up. What I would like to do he show a number with app icon (like Mail) to show number of new tasks. How can do that ? Where should I start ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569695/android-is-it-possible-to-update-a-imageview-imagebutton-with-a-number-to-show/5604787#5604787 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044828/drawing-number-badge-like-iphone-in-android