# How to show Notification Count on My App Icon on Home Screen in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest

The question is that 
Android places new alerts in the system wide notification bar while the iPhone places a notification directly over the specific app icon.

So what i have to do is that, i have to show my app icon with notification count received from C2dm receiver same as it is shown in iPhone with red oval showing the count.

i have referred this == [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android) and this link == [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569695/android-is-it-possible-to-update-a-imageview-imagebutton-with-a-number-to-show) to do it but no success has yet received.

please provide some guideline to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Though it might be possible to do such a thing it is **absolutely not recommended** to try and change the app's icon. This behaviour originates from iOS and is not used on Android at all.

You can create a widget that shows the unread count and takes the user to your app if the widget is clicked though. The Google Reader Android app offers a good example for that:

[image]