# show unread message count in app icon android

Tags: android, messaging

[image: How to implement unread message notification in our app like in messaging?]

How to implement unread message notification in our app like in messaging (in picture)?

any help appreciated

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665237/how-to-show-notification-count-on-my-app-icon-on-home-screen-in-android

Comment: but didn't get proper answer.

Comment: that answer is the proper answer. you shouldn't do that on android.

Answer (score -2):

```
public int getNumberOfUnreadMessages(Context context) {

   final Uri SMS_INBOX_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
   Cursor inboxCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX_URI, null, "read =  
    0", null, null);
   int unreadMessagesCount = inboxCursor.getCount();
   inboxCursor.close();
   return unreadMessagesCount;
   }
```

Comment: do try to answer the right thing ... try to understand what the user is asking for ..... @ Gaurav Jain