# How can I create badge number in icon launcher kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, numbers, badge

my story is make the number in top of icon or badge number like this
[home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWcrN.jpg)
[icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQAV8.jpg)
but it doesn't work all device why?
and how I solve it?

Comment: It’s not an Android feature. Individual launcher apps can choose to support it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show Notification Count on My App Icon on Home Screen in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665237/how-to-show-notification-count-on-my-app-icon-on-home-screen-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

if notify a notification android system add a badge to your app icon,
you can use below code to show notification

```
val id = "my_channel_01"
val name = getString(R.string.channel_name)
val descriptionText = getString(R.string.channel_description)
val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
val mChannel = NotificationChannel(id, name, importance).apply {
    description = descriptionText
    setShowBadge(true)
}
val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
```