# Add badge for tab widget android

Tags: android

I want to add badge for tab widget at android. i use android-viewbadger lib, but i not set badge show to image

[image]

here code:

```
 tabs = (TabWidget) findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
         badge = new BadgeView(this, tabs, 2);
        // badge.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.badge_28);
         badge.setBadgePosition(BadgeView.POSITION_TOP_RIGHT);
         badge.setWidth(14);
         badge.setHeight(14);
         badge.show();
```

Comment: It looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569695/android-is-it-possible-to-update-a-imageview-imagebutton-with-a-number-to-show/5604787#5604787) Stack Overflow question has a good answer.